# Convert MySQL date time 24 hour format to UNIX timestamp

Tags: mysql

I'm storing date time in `04-09-2019 10:31:AM`(4 September 2019 10:31 AM) in this format in MySQL table.

May I know how to convert this format to `unixtime` stamp in sql query

Comment: Why aren't you storing datetime values as datetime? Anyway, is that the 4th of September or the 9th of April?

Comment: Yes , but i'm  already stored in that format(04-09-2019 10:31:AM), So i need some solution to get unixtime stamp 
- it's 4 September 2019 10:31 AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to convert this into a proper **mysql** datetime using `str_to_date()` function.

```
str_to_date(dd, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%p')
```

Then after getting the correct **datetime** value, use `unix_timestamp()` function to convert it to unix timestamp.

```
select 
    unix_timestamp(str_to_date(dd, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%p'))
from test
```

try this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=8G00jR643x).

Comment: Yes, It's Working , Thank you soo much